# IIS web application "Build (web): Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: iis

I inherited an old web application built using IIS, and I'm trying to figure out how to build it. I'm running into this `Build (web): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error during build time. Aren't null object references supposed to be runtime errors, not compile errors? Can anyone explain to me what's happening here and how to fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can try to restart Visual studio and run it as administrator. Also, try to use "Clean" or "rebuild" instead of the normal "build" action.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the packages your projects reference? And do the assemblies in your bin folder match up with your web.config (check version numbers too)?

Edit: If the packages in the bin folder don't match, you can redownload them with NUGET -

1. note which packages are out of sync - grab their id values from the package nodes in the web.config
2. Inside your VS solution, check each project's references to see where the missing packages are referenced
3. Inside your VS solution, go to: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
4. for each missing package run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

   **Update-Package -Id <package_name> –reinstall**

where <package_name> == the id value you captured from the web.config at step 1.

Comment: I've manually copied a bunch of dlls to my bin folder, but I'm guessing I still need to add them via Add > Reference or Nuget Package Manager? How do I tell which have already been added? How do I tell if I need to add them via Reference or package manager? How do I tell if one is missing?

Comment: don''t manually copy stuff to your bin folder, if you clean and rebuild you'll have to do that again. Did the bin folder not contain the same versions of packages that your web.config was expecting? If so you need to redownload the packages (hopefully they were added with NUGET) - will update the answer with the steps for that.